# Can't retract close flag on locked question

Tags: bug, locked, retracted-flags

I flagged a question as unclear, and the flag is still pending. Now the question has been locked, and if I would want to retract my flag, I wouldn't be able to:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the system should act the same as when a mod take other action than locking (close/delete), aka auto mark users flags as helpful, as technically speaking, a mod checked the question after your flag.

Comment: The question is *locked*, which means "It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions". Retracting a flag is a new interaction. Why should you be able to retract a close-flag on a *locked* question? This seems to be rightfully [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Makyen Suppose I flag a question (on a site where I don't have enough rep to vote to close) for closure. A user comes by and fixes the question, but the author starts a rollback war and a moderator (who doesn't see close flags) locks the question with the other user's better revision. I don't see how the flag should be locked in and not retractable there.

Comment: @Makyen Also, the system does indeed accept new flags on locked posts (except historically locked posts), so I don't see why it shouldn't accept retractions of flags. In other words, how is casting a flag not an interaction when retracting is? Either both are or aren't.

Comment: That said, as the system invalidates any pending close reviews when a question is locked, it should also dismiss any pending close flags (under the internal status of "eventinvalidated", shown in public logs as "removed during a deletion" as it's currently only used in deletion-related cases).